# "th:text/each" not displaying data (Spring Boot/Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This application is supposed to take info on the corona virus from a webpage and output it into a nice table on our own webpage.

All table headers are there but the columns themselves are empty.

Thymeleaf doesn't display data passed to it in model despite data being passed correctly in the controller. I would appreciate any input, thank you.

**LocationStats.java (Edited)**

```
package io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.models;

public class LocationStats
{
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private int latestTotalCases;

    public String getState() { return this.state; }

    public void setState(String state) { this.state = state; }

    public String getCountry() { return this.country; }

    public void setCountry(String country) { this.country = country; }

    public int getLatestTotalCases() { return this.latestTotalCases; }

    public void setLatestTotalCases(int latestTotalCases) { this.latestTotalCases = latestTotalCases; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "LocationStats{" + "state='" + state + '\'' + ", country='" + country + '\'' + ", latestTotalCases=" + latestTotalCases + '}';
    }
}
```

**CoronaVirusDataService.java**

```
package io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.services;

import io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.models.LocationStats;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CoronaVirusDataService
{
    private static String VIRUS_DATA_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv";
    private List<LocationStats> allStats = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<LocationStats> getAllStats() { return allStats; }

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *")
    public void fetchVirusData() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        List<LocationStats> newStats = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(VIRUS_DATA_URL)).build();
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(httpResponse.body()); // Prints all data as expected

        StringReader csvBodyReader = new StringReader(httpResponse.body());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBodyReader);

        for(CSVRecord record : records)
        {
            LocationStats locationStat = new LocationStats();

            locationStat.setCountry(record.get("Country/Region"));
            locationStat.setState(record.get("Province/State"));
            locationStat.setLatestTotalCases(Integer.parseInt(record.get(record.size() - 1)));
            newStats.add(locationStat);
            
            System.out.println(locationStat); // Prints data as expected
        }

        this.allStats = newStats;
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.controllers;

import io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.models.LocationStats;
import io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.services.CoronaVirusDataService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    CoronaVirusDataService coronaVirusDataService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model)
    {
        List<LocationStats> allStats = coronaVirusDataService.getAllStats();
        int testNumber = 999; // For test attribute

        model.addAttribute("locationStats", allStats); // Actual attribute
        model.addAttribute("testInt", testNumber); // Test attribute

        return "home";
    }
}
```

**home.html (Edited)**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Corona Virus Tracker Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<h1 th:text="${testInt}">-1</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Total Cases</th>

    </tr>
    <tr th:each="locationStat : ${locationStats}">
        <td th:text="${locationStat.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

**CoronavirusTrackerApplication.java**

```
package io.javabrains.coronavirustracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class CoronavirusTrackerApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(CoronavirusTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>coronavirus-tracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>coronavirus-tracker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[Webpage's current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03n6c.png)

Comment: Are you sure the List `allStats` is not empty?

Comment: It's not. Also the test variable is not being shown, which we know to be not null.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf can only access data through getters. Add getters to your LocationStats class.

To clarify:

when you write in Thymeleaf:

```
<td th:text="${locationStat.state}"></td>
```

the `.state` in Thymeleaf is under the hood using the getter defined in your class to retrieve state. No getter = no thymeleaf representation.

Comment: I added getters, but where should they be used?

Comment: Thank you. My problem remains the same, rebuilt and restarted IntelliJ and whatnot as well. The getters are there in the LocationStats class.

Comment: Can you update the code to show your getters just so I can make sure they were written correctly.

Comment: Yeah they are fine - weird, try removing top line of your HTML, it has a mistake and you don't need it: `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">`

Comment: I removed it and edited the post to show that. Unfortunately, the data is still not displayed on the webpage.

Comment: doesnt make sense, I have checked you code, and it should work. Try opening localhost:8080 in incognito window to make sure the browser isnt using old cached version of the page.

Comment: I tried it with the same results. It's updating when I change header text and add headers and whatnot so I believe it's fine in that respect.

Comment: When you view the source in a browser, do you see `th:...` attributes in the code? (Is Thymeleaf getting parsed?)